# Numpy Convert N dimensional array into two dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a n-dimensional array with shape `(N,d_1,...,d_{n-1})`, I'd like to convert that array into a two dimensional array with shape `(N,D)`, where `D = \prod_i d_i`. Is there any neat trick in numpy to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.reshape()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method , along with [`array.shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) to get the shape of the original array and [`np.prod()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) to take the product of `d_1 , d_2 , ...` . Example -

```
In [22]: import numpy as np

In [23]: na = np.arange(10000).reshape((5,2,10,10,10))

In [26]: new_na = np.reshape(na, (na.shape[0], np.prod(na.shape[1:])))

In [27]: new_na.shape
Out[27]: (5, 2000)
```

Or a simpler version as suggested by @hpaulj in the comments -

```
In [31]: new_na = np.reshape(na, (na.shape[0], -1))

In [32]: new_na.shape
Out[32]: (5, 2000)
```

Comment: simpler still: `na.reshape(na.shape[0], -1)`

Comment: Nice, I will add that to the answer if you do not mind?